# ESP8266 wifi connection swift

Tags: swift, esp8266

How can I connect to the ESP8266 module via swift? I connect ESP8266's wifi through the phone's wifi menu, is it possible to do this with my swift app? Opens the connection with the ip address 192.168.4.1. I want to make this connection through my mobile application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to connect ESP device to access point using swift application. 
you need to use *Smart config Protocol*.

with the help of protocol you will able to connect your ESP with Any Access Point (Router) [link](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/network/esp_smartconfig.html)
also check [github](https://github.com/lou-lan/SmartConfig)

Comment: The application is not working properly, is there a more detailed source? I need help, thank you.

Comment: check out this project, Its working. 
 I implemented it in my live project. (https://github.com/EspressifApp)

Comment: I edited link, Please check it, You will find all projects here